# Unable to add mixed index in Titan

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, titan

I wanted to create a mixed index in titan so I used these gremlin commands

```
graph.tx().rollback()
mgmt.buildIndex('deviceIndex',Vertex.class).addKey(serialNumber,Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).addKey(manufacturer,Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).addKey(clas,Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).addKey(description,Mapping.TEXT.asParameter()).addKey(fw_version,Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).addKey(hw_version,Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).addKey(latitude).addKey(longitude).addKey(accuracy).addKey(measure_datetime).buildMixedIndex("search")
mgmt.commit()
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'deviceIndex').call()
```

what I get as output is:

> GraphIndexStatusReport[success=false, indexName='deviceIndex', targetStatus=REGISTERED, notConverged={device_longitude=ENABLED, device_latitude=ENABLED, device_description=ENABLED, device_class=ENABLED, device_serial_number=ENABLED, device_fw_version=ENABLED, device_accuracy=ENABLED, device_hw_version=ENABLED, device_manufacturer=ENABLED, measure_datetime=ENABLED}, converged={}, elapsed=PT1M0.234S]

Can you tell me why there is a `success=false` in the output. Why is the query failing?

=> edit

I used `g.V().has('device_latitude', (float)343.2435).toList()` and it didnt give me any warning that whole graph is being traversed. But I cannot search from elasticsearch ie

```
GET http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty
```

results in

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the index to see whether it is working or not?
Did you try to use graph.tx().commit() after mgmt.commit()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the result, it seems that the "deviceIndex" is registered but not enabled yet. You can try to see that the following code can solve your issue or not?

```
graph.tx().rollback()
mgmt.buildIndex('deviceIndex',Vertex.class).addKey(serialNumber,Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).addKey(manufacturer,Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).addKey(clas,Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).addKey(description,Mapping.TEXT.asParameter()).addKey(fw_version,Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).addKey(hw_version,Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).addKey(latitude).addKey(longitude).addKey(accuracy).addKey(measure_datetime).buildMixedIndex("search")
mgmt.commit()
graph.tx().commit()
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'deviceIndex').status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call()
```

Sometimes, specially in a remote data-stores (over high latency network) it takes time for index to become enabled instantly, waiting for index to become enabled may help your case.

Comment: Thanks! Its working! Can you tell me why `deviceIndex` might not be enabled automatically? as there is no mention of enabling an Index in titan [s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html)

Comment: @freeza Index will become enabled automatically if there is no problem to avoid it; however, it may take some time.